# Referencing environments and versions as parameters in Dialogflow CX for QA

Tags: dialogflow-cx

I would like to reference my current version in Dialogflow CX, so that when I trigger an intent like "what_version", I could return a fulfillment like: "session.params.environment.version"

Is this possible?

Comment: Theoretically Dialogflow CX is designed to be very flexible, so everything should be possible. However, I do not understand the use case. What do you mean by "version"? version of what? Why do you think it might be not possible?

Comment: @vitooh Thank you for the response. By version, I mean the version of CX that you can set in the "version" section of the "manage" tab in the CX console. When I am doing QA on a beta app of my bot, I would like to be able to ask the bot, "what version are you?" and have it respond back with the version that has been set in the "environment" section of the "manage" tab in the CX console.

Answer (score 1):

Accessing agent info is not possible directly, but as some comments said CX is very flexible so you could work around that.

My suggestion is:

1. Open the first version as draft
2. Go to the very first page in the Default Start Flow
3. In the "entry fulfilment" go under "parameters" and add a new parameter `version`:`<whatever>`
4. Repeat the process for all versions assigning them different version names
5. Now you have a `$session.params.version` parameter you can use in your answers!

Comment: Oh. That's smart! More manual than I would hope, but a super quick fix. Great thinking.